# How to show x,y,count(*) in 2-D by one SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example data in csv is

```
#row, col, number
y1,x1,1
y2,x2,1
y2,x2,1
y2,x3,1
```

If I use simple group SQL, it can displayed as one dimension

```
select y1,x1,count(*) from data group by 1,2 order by 1,2
```

The 1-D result is

```
row col count(*)
y1  x1  1
y2  x2  2
y2  x3  3
```

I want to show like

```
row x1 x2 x3
y1   1  0 0
y2   0  2 1
```

If the col is limited in only 'x1','x2','x3', is it possible to use one SQL to display as 2-D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT row,
SUM(CASE WHEN col= 'x1' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS x1,
SUM(CASE WHEN col= 'x2' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS x2,
SUM(CASE WHEN col= 'x3' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS x3
FROM data 
GROUP BY row;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc5e4/19)

```
select row,isnull(sum(x2),0) as X2,isnull(sum(x3),0) as X3
from(select row,case when col = 'x1'
then
cnt 
end as x1,
case when col = 'x2'
then
cnt 
end as x2,
case when col = 'x3'
then
cnt
end as x3
from
(select row,col,count(*) as cnt from test1 group by row,col ) as test)
as total
group by row
```